# Actualizar JTable de un JInternalFrame desde JDialog

Tags: java, java-swing

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio de Java que tiene un JInternalFrame y un JDialog que inserta datos a una tabla en el JInternalFrame.

¿Cómo puedo actualizar la tabla del JInternalFrame al presionar el botón "Insertar" dentro del JDialog sin tener que volver a cerrar y abrir el JInternalFrame?

Esta es la pantalla con la idea de mi pregunta (Cuando presiono en "Insertar" debería actualizarse la tabla):

[image: Question]

Sé que esto es posible agregando un `addWindowListener()` pero no sé cómo implementar esto.

Aquí algo del código del JInternalFrame JDialog:

```
public class JIFAbastos extends JInternalFrame{
    public JIFAbastos() {
    // this.addWindowListener();

    // Some code for update the table when the JDialog is close or pressed "Insertar" button.
    }


public class JDInsAbasto extends JDialog{
    public JDInsAbasto() {
    btnAdAb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    //Set variables and insert in table
    }
});
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo que hice fue crea un boton llamdo actualizar que me recargue los datos de la tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el la opciones de Code cuztomizer le di public y static para poder ejecutarlo desde otra ventana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo en la ventana emergente en el boton de guardar al final agregue una linea que ejecutara este botón y listo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si no quiere que se vea el boton le puede hacer un `btn_miboton.setVisible(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones, una vez que hagas click en el boton, cargar o llamar nuevamente la tabla.
La otra  opcion es con un windowActivated(WindowEvent e) esa opcion debes ejecturarla en el internalFrame, entonces cada vez que le hagan focus a la ventana, ejecutara el actualizar de la tabla

Comment: Pero, ¿Cómo cargar o llamar la tabla si el JDialog está en otra clase aparte?

Comment: ¿O cómo implementar el  windowActivated(WindowEvent e)?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando inserta nuevo producto haga:

```
JDialogAlgo jda = new JDialogAlgo(null, true); //esto lo abre como modal
jda.setVisible(true);
llenaTabla();     ///Aqui agregas nuevamente el metodo que llena tu tabla, este no se ejecuta hasta que se cierra tu modal.
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Edité tu respuesta para que el código que publicaste tome formato de código. Puedes hacer clic en _editar_ para ver cómo se logra. Utilizamos [markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) y algo de [html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) para lograrlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo agregándole como parámetro en el constructor de la JDInsAbasto el objeto que tiene el método que actualiza la tabla, suponiendo que hay un método actualizar en una clase "Abasto".

```
public class JDInsAbasto extends JDialog{
    public JDInsAbasto(Abasto abasto) {
    btnAdAb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            abasto.actualizar();
    }
}); 
}
```

Y haces que cuando inicie el dialogo desde el JInternalFrame le pase dicho objeto.